# jquery loading wrong version

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Issue #1 the following code is in my Master page

```
<html lang="en">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <title>Enerteck, industry leading performance catalysts for diesel fuels</title>
    <link href="Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="Styles/nav.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
    <link href="Content/jquery.lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.lightbox.min.js" ></script>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="HeaderContent" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>

<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
     <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    <Scripts>
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="MsAjaxBundle" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery.ui.combined" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle" />


    </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

The error in the console is
"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) blahblahblah/Scripts/jquery-1.8.1.js"

There is nowhere where I am referencing jquery version 1.8.1, I am clearly loading 1.8.2 and thats whats in the VS2012 project, installed via nuget package. The file is definitively in the scripts folder

My scripts arent running and Im assuming thats the reason because they work in jsfiddle

Comment: You should use absolute paths instead of relatives .. try it and see if the error is fixed

Comment: if you have a harcoded script tag for 1.82, what's this for `<asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />`??

Comment: Use `<%=Page.ResolveUrl("~/...")%>` syntax in your src and link attributes for giving the path of your files.

Comment: i removed the reference in charlietfl suggestion, which was placed there from nuget. this solved the problem

Comment: @dinotom  a quick look in the source view of page in a browser would have shown you the extra script tag.

Comment: is your content page having jquery 1.8.1?
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="HeaderContent" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to answer a similar question here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/35402418/1945517

Here's the gist of it, taking things one step at a time.

```
1. Print the version that the system is loading like so:
    console.log( "You are running jQuery version: " + $.fn.jquery);
2. View the source of the html page rendered.
3. Look for all the jquery source added, checking at <script> imports.
4. Then look for your source code where this is getting added.
5. Fix that, build, and repeat step 2 until you get the right version.
```

Good luck.